# SSIS Aggregating specific columns where = XXXX from Excel Source

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, ssis

In SSIS, I'm taking data from an Excel Source. This is what my data looks like:

```
+----+---------+--------+
| id |   Pet   | Amount |
+----+---------+--------+
| 1  | Cat     | 3      |
| 2  | Cat     | 2      |
| 3  | Dog     | 2      |
| 4  | Hamster | 3      |
| 5  | Fish    | 7      |
| 6  | Cat     | 1      |
| 7  | Cat     | 1      |
+----+---------+--------+
```

Now, my destination is a SQL Server Destination.

I want to be able to only sum up the **Amount** columns that have **Cat** listed:

```
+----+---------+--------+
| id |   Pet   | Amount |
+----+---------+--------+
| >1 | Cat     | 3      |
| >2 | Cat     | 2      |
| 3  | Dog     | 2      |
| 4  | Hamster | 3      |
| 5  | Fish    | 7      |
| >6 | Cat     | 1      |
| >7 | Cat     | 1      |
+----+---------+--------+
```

The total would be 7. Is there any way I could do this with an Excel data source? I know if I had a SQL / OLE DB source, I could do a query such as

```
  SELECT columnname FROM table
       WHERE Pet="Cat"
```

Please correct me if I'm wrong and tell me if you need clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in SSIS by using a Conditional Split transformation after the excel source and select only the rows where Pet=="Cat". After the Conditional Split you should plug an Aggregate transformation to sum up "Amount".
Alternatively you can omit the Conditional Split and get the sums directly from the Aggregate transformation.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT sum (Amount) AS "Number of cats"
 FROM table
 where Pet="Cat"
```

Is that what you were looking for?

the output would be like this:

```
  ________________
  |Number of Cats |
  |______7________|
```